# bootstrap 4 - grid columns aren't as expected

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <span class="badge badge-info badge-pill">2</span>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <p>short text to write.</p>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This code run in wrong way, becouse dont create one row with two columns in 2: 10 ratio, but second column goes down. I can add that when i fill with content second column that include 100 % width of itself - then everything is well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a container (`.container` / `.container-fluid`) to wrap your rows and columns.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <span class="badge badge-info badge-pill">2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p>short text to write.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/184407/

Comment: That's true, thank you for answer my simple question:), and correct the code.